# Fill an Entry in tkinter after randomly generated username

Tags: python, tkinter

SO, I have two file:

```
FOLDER
|_ generator.py
|_ gui.py
```

in `generation.py` there is a function that creates a random username:

```
import string
import random

def generate_username():
    username = "".join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters, 8))
    return username
if __name__ == '__main__':
    generate_username()
```

in `gui.py` there is a function that creates a Tkinter window with a label and a Entry:

```
from tkinter import * 
from generator import generate_username

def generate_window():
    top = Tk()
    label = Label(top, text="User Name")
    label.pack( side = LEFT)
    user_name = Entry(top, bd =5)
    user_name.pack(side = RIGHT)

    button_1 = Button(
    command=lambda: generate_username(),
    )
    top.mainloop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    generate_window()
```

My goal is to fill the Entry in the `gui.py` with the username generated in `generate_username` function in the other script when the button is pressed (hope I expressed myself well).
So basically the button has two jobs:

1. run the `generate_username` funtion
2. get the generated variable and write it on the Entry

I really have no idea hope to do it, I'm not even sure if it is possible.
Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can also use the `Entry` widget as an argument for your `generate_username` function in the other file (so that you don't need to `return`). Hope this helps.

```
from tkinter import * 
import random
import string


def generate_username(entry):
    username = "".join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters, 8))
    entry.delete(0, END)
    entry.insert(0, username)

def generate_window():
    top = Tk()
    label = Label(top, text="User Name")
    label.pack(side = LEFT)
    user_name = Entry(top, bd =5)
    user_name.pack(side ='left')

    button_1 = Button(text="Generate",
    command=lambda: generate_username(user_name),
    )
    button_1.pack(side='right')
    top.mainloop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    generate_window()
```

[image: Code demo]